# JPA mapping interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, interface

I am having trouble creating a mapping when the List type is an interface. It looks like I need to create an abstract class and use the discriminator column is this the case? I would rather not have to as the abstract class will just contain an abstract method and I would rather just keep the interface.

I have an interface lets call it Account

```
public interface Account {
 public void doStuff();
}
```

Now I have two concrete implementors of Account
OverSeasAccount and OverDrawnAccount

```
public class OverSeasAccount implements Account {
 public void doStuff() {
   //do overseas type stuff
 }
}
```

AND

```
public class OverDrawnAccount implements Account {
 public void doStuff() {
   //do overDrawn type stuff
 }
}
```

I have a class called Work with a List

```
private List<Account> accounts;
```

I am looking at discriminator fields but I seem to be only able do this for abstract classes. Is this the case? Any pointers appreciated. Can I use discriminators for interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is possible to to make an interface the supertype of a mapping. You may not be able to use annotations though. Annotations play well with xml config files so you might have to add a hibernate config file to your project with the mappings that you need. But you will be able to keep the annotations for the rest of your project.

[This](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/ANN-9) issue discusses it more. It seems to end with a suggestion as to how to do it with annotations so who knows. I would suggest that xml is still safer for now This [page](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/reference/en/html_single/#inheritance-tableperclass) of the docs explains the xml mapping needed.

Comment: Documentation on 'table per class' has moved here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tableperclass

Answer (score 1):

You can also introduce an abstract class without removing the interface.

```
// not an entity
public interface Account {
    public void doStuff();
}

@Entity
public abstract class BaseAccount {
    public void doStuff();
}


@Entity
public class OverSeasAccount extends AbstractAccount {
    public void doStuff() { ... }
}

@Entity
public class OverDrawnAccount extends AbstractAccount {
    public void doStuff() { ... }
}
```